# How would you create a table view that, using a segue, has another table view inside each cell using core data?

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, cell

So, I am creating this app that involves the creation of routines in a table view. Once you create this routine in the table view, you are then given the option to look inside this routine. Once you look inside it, you are presented with another table view that holds a set of tasks each, all of these created by the user. I am using Core Data, and I'm having problems in my data model assigning the task to the routine that it's in. What happens in the simulator is that all of the tasks that I've created can be seen in all of the routines. This is not the behavior that I want at all, what I am looking for is for each routine to have its own individual tasks. How would you do this? Please keep in mind that I am using Core Data.

Comment: Show (or explain) your data model; it sounds like you have `routine` entities and `task` entities, but you have either not defined, or not populated, the relationship between them.

Comment: @pbasdf My model is fairly simple. You pretty much have two main objects: Routine objects and Task objects. These objects all have a name property (String). When the user clicks the add button, they can set their name values and it is in the done function that their names are actually saved. However, I am yet to establish, or define as you said it, the relationship between them so that I can achieved the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define the relationship between the two entities.  In the model editor, ctrl-drag from the `Routine` entity to the `Task` entity.  This will create a new relationship between the two entities (indicated by the line):

[image: Model Editor]

Select the `newRelationship` in the `Routine` entity, and rename it to "tasks"(in the panel on the right), and change the "Type" to "To Many" - each `Routine` can have many `Tasks`.  Likewise rename the `newRelationship` in the `Task` entity to "routine" (you should also decide whether each `Task` can belong to many `Routines`, or only one, and change the "Type" accordingly; I've assumed it will be "To One"):

[image: Model Editor after changing relationships]

The "Type" is indicated by the arrowhead - single for "To One" and double for "To Many".  (You should also look through the CoreData docs and decide what "delete rule" you want.)

That is the relationship is defined.  To simplify populating the relationship, it's worth generating `NSManagedObject` subclasses for each of your entities.  Then you can access their properties (and relationships) using dot notation.  The Model Editor can generate the subclass definitions for you - in the Editor menu, "Create NSManagedObject subclass":

[image: Menu]

Follow through the various dialogs and a .swift file will be created for each Entity.  Now to populate the relationship is easy - if you have a `Routine` object, say `myRoutine`, and a `Task` object called `myTask`, just use

```
myTask.routine = myRoutine
```

This will automatically set the relationship both ways - from `myRoutine` to `myTask` and vice versa.

Now, define a property ("myRoutine") in your second view controller of type `Routine`.  When you segue from your first view controller, set the value of `myRoutine` to the chosen `Routine`.  Then, after creating any new `Task` objects, set their `routine` to myRoutine, as above.  Or if you are only displaying the tasks for the chosen routine, you can use `myRoutine.tasks` (which is a NSSet of all the `Task` objects for the chosen `Routine`) as the datasource for the table view in your second view controller.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75529/discussion-on-answer-by-pbasdf-how-would-you-create-a-table-view-that-using-a-s).